# Unity - How to resolve an inherited base constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, unity-container

Using Unity & Prism, trying to resolve an interface at run-time.

Registration

```
this.unityContainer.RegisterType<IMyValidationResult, MyValidationResult>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
```

Concrete implementation

```
public class MyValidationResult : ValidationResult , IMyValidationResult
{       
    public MyValidationResult(string message, string tag)
        : base(message, null, "", tag, null)
    { }

    public MyValidationResult(string message, string tag = "", string key = "")
        : base(message, null, key, tag, null)
    { }

    // Etc.
```

I am then injecting the `IMyValidationResult` into a view model via constructor injection. Inherited `ValidationResult` is the `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation` class. Obviously the concrete type cannot be resolved at run time. Is there a way to handle these base constructors in the Unity `RegisterType`?

Comment: What do you mean by "the concrete type cannot be resolved at run time" exactly? Isn't your `MyValidationResult` being resolved by the container or what happens? `MyValidationResult` will invoke the constructor of the base class upon creation.

Comment: Where do intent to get message and tag from? IMHO I don't thing you are using DI correct. An IoC container should only be placed at the root of the application. DI is not good, if your dependencies - like in your case - is flexible and can change. DI is for dependencies and this looks more like data, which I would never put in side an IoC container.

Answer (score 0):

The literal answer to your question is: you can't.

You resolve objects rather than constructors.

You should add any parameters you will need on base in the ctor of the inherited ctor, A base class is never going to be resolved because it's not instantiated separately. The leaf class you're resolving is the thing being instantiated.

Meaning whatever key is, you need to add that as a parameter to the ctor of  MyValidationResult and provide it to Unity.

Or

Add some code into MyValidationResult ctor to get or instantiate key and supply it to the base ctor.

Either way.

Ensure the ctor with the most parameters is the one you're relying on.

It's usually a bad idea to have multiple ctor when you're using DI since it can easily confuse you as to which one will be used.

Comment: You resolve objects rather than constructors. - Yes I realise this...